# Chromium-browser libprotobuf ERROR when using PPAPI flash --> Segmentation fault

Tags: 16.04, flash, chromium

I can't start up the chromium-browser after an update. `adobe-flash-properties-gtk:amd64` and `adobe-flashplugin:amd64` were upgraded today. How do I fix this issue?

```
$ chromium-browser 
Using PPAPI flash.
[libprotobuf ERROR ../../third_party/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:121] Can't parse message of type "in_memory_url_index.InMemoryURLIndexCacheItem" because it is missing required fields: (cannot determine missing fields for lite message)
Segmentation fault
```

Files upgraded:

```
Upgrade: libunity-settings-daemon1:amd64 (15.04.1+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu2, 15.04.1+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu3), lib32ubsan0:amd64 (7.3.0-21ubuntu1~16.04, 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~16.04~ppa1), openssl:amd64 (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13, 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.14), adobe-flash-properties-gtk:amd64 (1:20181120.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 1:20181205.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libraw15:amd64 (0.17.1-1ubuntu0.3, 0.17.1-1ubuntu0.4), libgs9:amd64 (9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu0.16.04.3), gcc-7-base:amd64 (7.3.0-21ubuntu1~16.04, 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~16.04~ppa1), libcilkrts5:amd64 (7.3.0-21ubuntu1~16.04, 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~16.04~ppa1), libwavpack1:amd64 (4.75.2-2ubuntu0.1, 4.75.2-2ubuntu0.2), lib32cilkrts5:amd64 (7.3.0-21ubuntu1~16.04, 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~16.04~ppa1), adobe-flashplugin:amd64 (1:20181120.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 1:20181205.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libx32cilkrts5:amd64 (7.3.0-21ubuntu1~16.04, 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~16.04~ppa1), libubsan0:amd64 (7.3.0-21ubuntu1~16.04, 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~16.04~ppa1), hwdata:amd64 (0.267-1, 0.267-1ubuntu2), ghostscript:amd64 (9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu0.16.04.3), libssl-dev:amd64 (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13, 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.14), libssl-doc:amd64 (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13, 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.14), ghostscript-x:amd64 (9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu0.16.04.3), libgs9-common:amd64 (9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu0.16.04.3), libx32ubsan0:amd64 (7.3.0-21ubuntu1~16.04, 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~16.04~ppa1), unity-settings-daemon:amd64 (15.04.1+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu2, 15.04.1+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu3), libssl1.0.0:amd64 (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13, 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.14)
Remove: linux-image-4.4.0-139-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-139.165), linux-headers-4.4.0-139:amd64 (4.4.0-139.165), linux-image-extra-4.4.0-139-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-139.165), linux-headers-4.4.0-139-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-139.165)
```

**Edit**: The chromium-browser was also upgraded 3 days ago.

```
chromium-browser:amd64 (70.0.3538.77-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 70.0.3538.110-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra:amd64 (70.0.3538.77-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 70.0.3538.110-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), chromium-browser-l10n:amd64 (70.0.3538.77-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 70.0.3538.110-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by uninstalling and reinstalling the `chromium-browser` via `Software Install`.